# Changing localStorage to a different value and keeping it after refresh

Tags: javascript

When the page loads up a localStorage  var is created.

```
localStorage.setItem("welcomeScreen", "true");
var checkScreen = localStorage.getItem("welcomeScreen");
```

An if statement is also called. `if (checkscreen == "true"){//do something}`

All of that code works, but when something in the welcome screen is pressed it updates the item `localStorage.setItem("welcomeScreen", "false")` Then another if is called

`if (checkscreen == "false"){//do something}`

It never does that if statement because if I reload the page it always resets the item to `"true"`.

How can I update the item and keep it like that when refreshed? Thanks.

Comment: What updates the value to false ?

Comment: @Rayon when a button is clicked in the welcome screen it does this `localStorage.setItem("welcome", "false");`

Comment: You should be having a condition whenever you are updating the value...

Comment: @Rayon Ok let me try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is happening somewhere where you're pressing the key on welcome screen probably there's some condition which updates the `localStoarge` item.
One more suggestion here-
    if (checkscreen == "true") and if (checkscreen)
are the same. So you can write only `if (checkscreen)`